# Navigation Issue in my flutter Application. Unable to redirect to the required page or screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation, provider, changenotifier

Below code mainform.dart  when  run individually i.e keeping Dart entrypint: as mainform.dart  working fine and redirecting  or navigating to the correct page i.e Feed();

mainform.dart

```
import 'package:sqlite_crud_flutter/detail.dart';
import 'package:sqlite_crud_flutter/login.dart';
import 'package:sqlite_crud_flutter/notifier/food_notifier.dart';
import 'package:sqlite_crud_flutter/feed.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'notifier/auth_notifier.dart';


void main() => runApp(MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => AuthNotifier(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => FoodNotifier(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MainFormPage(),
    ));

class MainFormPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Application Name',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        accentColor: Colors.lightBlue,
      ),
      home: Consumer<AuthNotifier>(
        builder: (context, notifier, child) {
          return  Feed();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But where as when I want to redirect to the Feed() page from another screen or page of my main application using

```
 onTap: () {

Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
MainFormPage()

)
);

},
```

I am seeing a blank screen with error

> Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'"

How to the Feed page from another screen?

Screenshot of the error shown on mobile when debugged:

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Can you add logs with error from console to the question?

Comment: Ok  I have already  given the error shown i.e .                                                              " Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty'" . I will try to find out the  error log as well.

Comment: The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Consumer<AuthNotifier> 
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Provider._inheritedElementOf (package:provider/src/provider.dart:309:7)
#1      Provider.of (package:provider/src/provider.dart:261:30)
#2      Consumer.buildWithChild (package:provider/src/consumer.dart:177:16)
#3      SingleChildStatelessWidget.build (package:nested/nested.dart:260:41)
#4      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4620:28)

Comment: @srk2K21 you mean to say when you are navigating from second page to `MainFormPage()` then this error occurred?

Comment: Yes  I have a main Application and in that  from one of the page or screen ex "mobiles.dart" page  I want to redirect to the  MainFormPage() which should ultimately redirect me to the Feed page i.e Feed() as shown in the code

Comment: Hi Shubham please try to fix my problem asap..if you still have any queries please let me know

Comment: Anyone still trying to fix my issue. Please et me know if you have any queries still?

Comment: Hi Shubham still trying to fix my issue. Please et me know if you have any queries still?

Comment: somebody please try to fix my blank screen widget issue. Urgent

Comment: Hi fartem and shubham please try to fix this issue asap.

Comment: No body trying to fix this issue.